# Product details tab renaming

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs

How can i change the product details tab renamed "Details" to "Description"?
I am using magento 1.9.2 and easy tabs extension.

1. "Details+care" and "Size guide" from easy tab with value of custom attribute of product.
2. "Details" from easy tab product description with value of  default product description.
3. Now I needed to change the tab name to "Details" to "Description".

http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets/percale-venice-set.html#product_tabs_size-guide

Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to easytabs.xml and change there "Details" to "Description"? and that will work.

Comment: <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <block type="easytabs/tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="tm_easytabs/general/enabled">
                    <template>tm/easytabs/tabs.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

Comment: there is no name changing option in easytab

Comment: give me link of easytab extesnion

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-products-tabs-extension-for-magento.html

Comment: http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets/percale-venice-set.html

Comment: here i added easy tab